# How do I write a SQL Update to only update rows if the following condition matches?

Tags: sql

I have quite a few tables, so I'll try my best to describe it.

```
Environment Table
ID | CUSTOMER_ID| ALLOW_ACCESS|
```

```
CUSTOMER TABLE
|ID|
```

```
CUSTOMER_CARD
|ID| CUSTOMER_ID |
```

```
APPLICATION TABLE
|ID| NAME |
```

```
APP_ROLE TABLE
|ID| APPLICATION_ID| NAME |
```

```
COMBINE_TABLES
|ID|CUSTOMER_ID |CUSTOMER_CARD_ID |ENVIRONMENT_ID| APP_ROLE_ID|
```

Assume these tables are populated with some entries with the proper foreign key constraints.

What I want to do is update all rows in the `Environment` table for all customers to set `ALLOW_ACCESS=1` if they either have ZERO entries in the `CUSTOMER_CARD` table, or if they do have an entry, but the `COMBINE_TABLES` table does not have an entry where the APPLICATION NAME is `Foo` and the APP_ROLE Name is `Bar`

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM ENVIRONMENT TE WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM COMBINE_TABLES CT INNER JOIN APP_ROLE AR ON CT.APP_ROLE_ID = AR.ID INNER JOIN APPLICATION A ON A.ID = AR.APP_ID WHERE TE.ID = CT.TENANT_ENV_ID AND A.NAME = 'Foo' AND AR.NAME = 'Bar')
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Please only tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using. Thanks.

Comment: @Parfait I added my attempt

Comment: Great. Please line break the SQL for readability and add what is wrong with the attempt (i.e., error, undesired results)? Also, why are you attempting `SELECT` when you want to `UPDATE`? Please tag your RDBMS as different SQL dialects handle `UPDATE` very differently.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested):

```
UPDATE environment e 
SET allow_access=1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 
    FROM customer_card
    WHERE customer_id = e.customer_id)
 OR EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 
     FROM  customer_card cc
      JOIN combine_tables ct ON ct.customer_id = cc.customer_id
      JOIN app_role  ar ON ar.id = ct.app_role_id AND ar.name = 'Bar'
      JOIN application a ON ar.APPLICATION_ID = a.id AND a.name = 'Foo'
    WHERE cc.customer_id = e.customer_id);
```

Comment: Ok... that looks promising. But wouldn't the second condition also be OR NOT EXISTS

Comment: Can it be simplified: SELECT * FROM ENVIRONMENT TE 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM COMBINE_TABLES CT
INNER JOIN APP_ROLE AR ON CT.APP_ROLE_ID = AR.ID 
INNER JOIN APPLICATION A ON A.ID = AR.APP_ID 
WHERE TE.ID = CT.TENANT_ENV_ID
AND A.NAME = 'Foo'
AND AR.NAME = 'Bar')

Comment: @AlexLen I do not see the simplier way here as first contition says ` have ZERO entries` and second says they have entries with additional conditions. Not exists for second codtion will also update if app-role pair is like app='Dooh' role='nvm'